# Codeigniter variable-length parameter list

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making a tutorialsystem with Codeigniter, but I'm a bit stuck with using subcategories for my tutorials.

The URL-structure is like this: /tutorials/test/123/this-is-a-tutorial

- tutorials is the controller
- test is a shortcode for the category
- 123 is the tutorial ID (used in the SQL query)
- this-is-a-tutorial is just a slug to prettify the URL

What I do is passing the category as a first parameter and the ID as a second parameter to my controller function:

```
public function tutorial($category = NULL, $tutorial_id = NULL);
```

Now, if I want subcategories (unlimited depth), like: /tutorials/test/test2/123/another-tutorial. How would I implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For reading infinite arguments, you have at least two useful tools:

- [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)
- The [URI class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)

So in your controller:

- Pop the last segment/argument (this is your slug, not needed)
- Assume the last argument is the tutorial ID
- Assume the rest are categories

Something like this:

```
public function tutorial()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    // ...or use $this->uri->segment_array()

    $slug = array_pop($args);
    $tutorial_id = array_pop($args); // Might want to make sure this is a digit

    // $args are your categories in order
    // Your code here
}
```

The rest of the code and the validation depends on what specifically you want to do with the arguments.

Comment: In PHP 5.6+, you can use the ... token. Like: function sum(...$numbers) { foreach($numbers as $n) php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 0):

If you need variable categories you could use the [URI](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) class: `$this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n)`

Comment: The categories are dynamic and are also pulled from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you may want to consider is CodeIgniter's controller function remapping functionality which you can use to override the default behaviour. You would be able to define a single function inside a controller that would handle all the calls to that controller and have the remaining URI parameters passed in as an array. You could then do whatever you want with them.

See [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) for the docs reference on the matter.

Comment: That looks interesting too. I might use that for something else I have in mind.